# How to determine a 3rd party type instance method is thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using a 3rd party type instance method. I have no access to the source code. How to determine if the method is thread safe?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: Can you ask them? Could you disassemble the binary?

Comment: @JonSkeet Unfortunately, there's not much document.

Comment: It is an **instance** method, I have a hunch that it is not thread-safe.

Comment: You could generate a bunch of threads (200+) that simultaneously and repeatedly access the instance method and see if they get the predicted result.  You could also do the same and time each thread and tell you how long it was in the method.  If the method is locked, it will almost certainly take longer for the threads to access it than if it's not because they'll be blocked.

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse: it would not prove general thread safety, it would only prove a partial attempt for thread safety, and I suppose that the author of the question does not really care if the method is only partially thread safe...

Comment: Which is why I didn't put it here as an "answer" - only a comment.  It would probably give you an idea if the method was intended to be thread safe, though I suppose they could encounter locks on submethods that are threadsafe while others that aren't.  Still if you access the same method a million times on 1000 threads and everything comes back legit, odds are pretty good.

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse indeed, just pretty good :/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot establish that it is thread safe, only the designer of the method can do that.
Even with access to the source code of the function, it would not necessarily help as any access to variables external to the method, and even if synchronized, could be plagued with parallel incoherent accesses.

Your only chance is to get the information from the designer of the method/type.

Comment: If you decompile the method and see that it is indeed thread safe despite no documentation saying it is, that only means that this method is thread safe in this version of the library. Upgrade the library and the implementation might change.

Comment: @ta.speot.is we are OK on this